# MYSQL: ERROR 2027 (HY000): Malformed packet

Tags: mysql, tcp

Não estou conseguindo conectar um servidor MySQL remotamente.
A conexão parece estar ok pois com telnet [ip] [porta] obtenho resposta:

```
4.1.3b-beta-nt-max▒@\0v'[uZ,B{efSLa$,Q4N
```

Quando executo por linha de comando ou pelo MySQL Workbench 6.3

```
mysql -u[user] -p -h [host]
```

Obtenho o mesmo erro 
**ERROR 2027 (HY000): Malformed packet**

Comment: Leva a crer que seja um Bug nesta versão especifica, este `-Beta` me faz suspeitar que você esta usando uma versão beta do mysqlworkbench, talvez possa tentar instalar uma versão mais antiga, eu tive alguns problemas com o Workbench e Windows, especificamente no Windows7

Comment: Muito obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento! Vou verificar isso. Elabore uma resposta, este seu comentário vale pontos!!!!

Comment: EdvaldoSilva assim que você conseguir me avisa que eu formulo ;)

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa atualizar (diretamente no servidor) a senha desse usuário encriptada com o método "old_password":

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'meuusuario'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('meupassword');`

Dessa maneira você vai conseguir efetuar login em uma versão antiga do servidor MysqL, usando o Workbench nas versões mais recentes.