# Importar tabela excel direto para mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, csv, importação

Estou usando o seguinte código para tentar importar 30 mil registros csv para um bd [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) no servidor hostgator

```
load data local infile 'public_html/empresa.csv' into table empresa
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(id_empresa,cnpj, empresa);
```

Porém da o seguinte erro:

> #2027 - Malformed packet

Já tentei pelo painel do [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) no importar dados, já tentei outros comandos, tudo e não consigo. Alguém pode me ajudar? Se desejar, passo senha e usuário para ver o que ocorre .

Comment: [MYSQL: ERROR 2027 (HY000): Malformed packet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228641/70)

Comment: Infelizmente não vou conseguir trazer a resposta ideal, pois há vários tipos de situações onde isso ocorre, apenas coisas que talvez possam ajudar. Primeiro vi que é bem comum receber esse erro ao usar o `LOAD DATA INFILE`, você pode tentar atualizar o libmysql.dll, ou como você está o usando o servidor do hostgator falar diretamente com eles. Recomendo também olhar essa discussão pode ajudar muito: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102567/sql-error-2027-malformed-packet

Comment: Se nem o HOSTGATOR esta respondendo minha solicitação é sinal que eu to ferrado mesmo. Vlw , obrigado